# Unable to Set Device Policy Android Phone

Tags: android

I am encountering an error setting the device owner on an android device using the steps below.  This has worked in the past on other devices:

1. Perform Factory reset
2. Enable debug mode on device
3. From command line run the following on the connected device:

   ```
   adb install -r myapp.apk
   adb shell "dpm set-device-owner com.mydomain.myapp/.ServiceDeviceAdminReceiver"
   ```

The following error occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to set the device owner because there are already some accounts on the device
```

Under  Settings > Accounts  (there are no accounts listed)

Under Settings > Security > Device Administrators (there are 2 apps and both are unchecked):
Android Device Manager

Myapp

I then ran the following commands and received the following output:

```
adb shell pm list users
Users:
    UserInfo{0:Owner:13} running


adb shell dumpsys device_policy
Current Device Policy Manager state:
    Enabled Device Admins (User 0):

    mPasswordOwner=-1
```

Any suggestions on what I can do to set the device owner?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all accounts from the device too, that means no sign in of any sort, even google, skip that step after factory reset

Comment: Under Settings > Accounts (there are no accounts listed)

Comment: the device should be totally un-setted up, that means no other app installed except your owner app and pre installed apps, check for any apps installed

Comment: In step 1 the device is factory reset.  So only the owner app and pre-installed apps are there.